# how to change some string based on database php

Tags: php, arrays

guys i have problem in change some part of string in `$menu_image` with this following code  :

```
string(62) "/asset/images/menu/Singapore/365/225/509/509_RhWu2f4G_s130.jpg"
```

i want trying to change the `225` with a new string of number which i save it in `$category_id`

example if i have `226` in `$category_id` than, `$menu_image` should be like this :

```
string(62) "/asset/images/menu/Singapore/365/226/509/509_RhWu2f4G_s130.jpg"
```

guys is that possible to change that `225`?

thank you (:

Comment: Yes, it is possible, - Is it always `225` that you want to replace with something else? - In any case, try and play with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) - `str_replace ('225','226',$string);`

Comment: @Epodax another question, how about if in there string have same number like 365 be 225, so it would be `225/225` if i using `str_replace` that `225` will be change to new string

Comment: @Kelvin Indeed it will. Is the string you want to replace always at the same position (i.e after `/asset/images/menu/Singapore/A_NUMBER/THE_NUMBER_TO_CHANGE/...` ? ANd is it always a number ?

Comment: yes it will in the same position, and will always return number. @roberto06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is always in same position, then just explode your code first:

```
$split=array_map('trim', explode("/",$menu_image));
$split[6] = $category_id;
$menu_image_link = implode("/",$split);
```

and your `$menu_image_link` will return:

```
string(62) "/asset/images/menu/Singapore/365/".$category_id."/509/509_RhWu2f4G_s130.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split the string, replace the part you want, then join it back, as such :

```
<?php
$string = '/asset/images/menu/Singapore/365/225/509/509_RhWu2f4G_s130.jpg';
$new_id = '226';
$string_array = explode('/', $string);
$string_array[6] = $new_id; // Replacing 6th element which is the number we're looking for
$string = implode('/', $string_array);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of the 255 being hard coded if you have the value in a `variable` called `$category_id`, you should concatenate the `variable` into the `string` used for the `image` path. E.g. `"/asset/images/menu/Singapore/365/" . $category_id . "/509/509_ RhWu2f4G_s130.jpg"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: i cant do that, as i said this `"/asset/images/menu/Singapore/365/226/509/509_RhWu2f4G_s130.jpg"` is coming from database dude!!

Comment: Okay sorry I did not re-read the title, if that is the case then as per Epodax's suggestion you will need to use `str_replace`. I believe using `str_replace('255', $category_id, $string);` with `$string` being the part of your array containing the image path, is what you are after.

Comment: check the above comment

Comment: Provided that the 255 you want to replace is always in the same position you can use `substr_replace($string, $category_id, 33, -1)` the only problem with this occurs when the 365 (or whatever number it may be) becomes 4 digits long.

Comment: Apologies, there is an error in the above code, the -1 should be 3, specifying the length to replace.